# Notifying all users of my app that there is new information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-app-requests

The app we're building wants to notify all of its users that there is new information available.

Basically, the users follow hints to find a certain place on a map to win a prize.
For a couple of weeks there will be new hints available at specific times, 3 times a day.

We're now looking into using App-to-user requests but the requests stick around, unlike a message in there news feed, so it might look spammy. It also doesn't get the message across directly but just shows "App has a new request for you".

What is the best way to let **all** of the users know that the new hint is available? We don't want to force them to like our Page. We don't want to e-mail them either.

Comment: You can't do this... While your intentions might be okay, allowing this functionality would open a gaping hole for spammers to jump in...  I think you are better of requesting users emails and then updating them like that.  You say that you don't want to email the users - I assume that is because you don't the users to feel like they are being spammed - how would what you want differ from this?  You are sending information to users when they did not explicitly request it.  If they give you their email address - they are willing to receive updates...

Comment: _„but the requests stick around”_ - only as long as the user has not reacted on them. When he does, it is __your__ responsibility to delete them.

Comment: You could also delete the requests after X days if the user never came back

Comment: @Lix I think I am trying to walk a thin line between spamming and actually being informative. 3 e-mails a day seems like proper spam, 3 messages in their news feed do not. Especially if those messages just blend in with the rest of their newsfeed. Sadly, this isn't possibly without forcing a like on a page it seems. You'd say I could inform the user that if they do want updates, they need to opt-in (either a like on a page or just by email) but we know people won't do this. Mostly out of lazyness.

Comment: @jer - This is 100% subjective.  Even one such "post" notifying me of an update (in my eyes) would be spam as I did not explicitly request that info...  If your users **want** to receive updates from your page, ask them to `LIKE` it.  That is the correct way to connect with "fans" on Facebook and update them about new info on your page.

Comment: @Lix I understand that. I was just hoping there would be a permission request for this sort of thing (we're already requesting email for other purposes). I've tried to push the "ask for a like" method on the client before, might want to make it clear this time that it's the only way not to be a spammer. Thanks.